# What is the best collection type for constantly changing table representation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid

I am representing a table in WPF by using MVVM. The data type of each element from the table is int, something like this:

```
0 1 2 3 1 2 12
0 1 3 3 1 3 12
0 1 2 3 5 2 12
0 1 2 3 1 2 12
```

Similar to a multi dimensional array. The data from the table is constantly changing (from another thread, example: each second)

I have managed doing so by using a DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CalculatedTable}">                
        </DataGrid>
```

and the CalculatedTable which I bound to is a *DataTable*

an example of how I use it for initializing:

```
 CalculatedTable.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
 CalculatedTable.Columns.Add("2", typeof(int));
 CalculatedTable.Columns.Add("3", typeof(int));
 CalculatedTable.Columns.Add("4", typeof(int));
 CalculatedTable.Columns.Add("5", typeof(int));

 CalculatedTable.Rows.Add(10, 12, 15, 2, 5);
 CalculatedTable.Rows.Add(54, 21, 15, 2, 1);
 CalculatedTable.Rows.Add(24, 13, 25, 11, 1);
 CalculatedTable.Rows.Add(21, 32, 15, 13, 3);
 CalculatedTable.Rows.Add(56, 45, 35, 19, 8);
```

example of how I change it:

```
Queue(() =>
            {               
            UpdateTable();
            });   

void UpdateTable(){
    DataRow dr = CalculatedTable.Rows[i];
    addon = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
    dr[0] = addon + 1;
    OnPropertyChange(nameof(CalculatedTable));
    Queue(() =>
            {               
            UpdateTable();    
            });            
}
```

I am worrying if DataTable and DataGrid is the best way to represent this kind of data or if there would be another type of Collection which would better suit my need. Also It looks like this solution is not 100% thread safe because I have the following exception from time to time in my output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get '1' value (type 'Int32')
>   from '' (type 'DataRowView'). BindingExpression:Path=1;
>   DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=31910704); target element is
>   'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   IndexOutOfRangeException:'System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
>   outside the bounds of the array.    at
>   System.Data.Common.Int32Storage.Get(Int32 record)    at
>   System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(DataColumn column, DataRowVersion
>   version)    at System.Data.DataRowView.GetColumnValue(DataColumn
>   column)    at System.Data.DataColumnPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object
>   component)    at MS.Internal.Data.ValueTable.GetValue(Object item,
>   PropertyDescriptor pd, Boolean indexerIsNext)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
>   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'

Answer (score 1):

The collection type shouldn't really matter as far as the data binding is concerned. Certain kind of collections have characteristics that makes it faster to look up an item etc., but that's another story.

You should only bind to the source collection *once* and then update the individual items in the collection. This requires the data type to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The built-in `DataRowView` class does.

If items may be added or removed from the collection dynamically, you want to use a collection that implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` or the `IBindingListView` interface. There is the `ObservableCollection<T>` class or the `DataView` class that you are currently using.

Also note that there is no reason to use a `DataGrid` if you don't intend to edit the data. Then you might as well use a `ListView` with a `GridView`.

Comment: So if I use DataView is just like using an ObservableCollection, any change on the actual datatable will change the view itself?

Comment: Yes, the view will be changed when you set the value of a cell in the DataTable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Please remember to accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) would best fit your needs.

You can just bind to it and .Net will take care of the rest.